# Laravel local scope on eager load

Tags: php, laravel-5, eager-loading

Lets say I have three tables in DB (and three models).

1. Destination (id, title, region_id)
2. Region (id, title)
3. Translations (id, region_id; nullable, destination_id; nullable, translated_value)

Then I have those relations and scopes defined:

1. Destination

   ```
   public function getRegion(){
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Region', 'region_id')->translate();}

   public function scopeTranslate($query){
       return $query->join('translations', function($join){
       $join->on('destinations.id', '=', 'translations.destination_id')
          ->where('language_code', app()->getLocale());
   })->select('destinations.*', 'translations.value as translated_title');}
   ```
2. Region

   ```
   public function scopeTranslate($query){
       return $query->join('lm_translations', function($join){
       $join->on('regions.id', '=', 'lm_translations.region_id')
           ->where('language_code', app()->getLocale());
   })->select('regions.*', 'lm_translations.value as translated_title');}
   ```

Then I fetch destinations and eager load translations on both.

```
 $destinations = Destination::whereHas('getRegion')
     ->with('getRegion')->translate()->get();
```

**Problem:**
Region gets translation from destination when eager loading, but if I load it usualy everything is fine.

I ran queries directly in DB and they are executed as they should, this means eager loading is not connecting relations correctly.

Where is the catch?

Comment: I don't think a query scope is going to accomplish what you're setting out to do.  The translate() call is only going to be on the Destination query, you aren't making use of the Region model in this query, only including the related Region models once the query has been run.

Comment: Yes but getRegion() is using translate scope. If I load it without eager load it works,  but then I have around 500 queries. I just need titles always translated.

Comment: Ok, I haven't tried running a query scope on a relation before.  Do you have query logging enabled to see what is actually being sent?

Comment: I am using barryvdh/debugbar.. Here is a gist of sql beeing run https://gist.github.com/tsobocan/9e4f3146e804b13b3b6820dbdbce10f7

Comment: Are you confident you're joining lm_translations in the Region model?  It looks like everything is okay except for the join table being translations.

Comment: Yes, it was just typo in gist.